# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application: instantiable even if it's an interface?

Tags: c#, excel, interface, instantiation

So i was reading this article[1], and there's a section "To declare a method that exports account information to Excel" with the following example:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
...
static void DisplayInExcel(IEnumerable<Account> accounts)
{
   var excelApp = new Excel.Application();
   ...
}
```

Excel.Application is an interface. How is this possible?

I thought interfaces weren't instantiable. Thanks!

[1] https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264733.aspx

Comment: It's intantiating an object that implements that interface but is returning it typed as the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed `Excel.Application()` is not instanciation but rather a property witch type is Application Interface. So how is instantiated, well it's thanks to the following Attributes

```
[CoClass(typeof(ApplicationClass))].
```

ApplicationClass implement Application(interface) and returns a property of type of Application interface.

```
[CoClass(typeof(ApplicationClass))]
[Guid("000208D5-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
public interface Application : _Application, AppEvents_Event
{
}
```

Take a look at this code.

```
private static void DisplayInExcel(IEnumerable<string> accounts)
{
  var excelApp = new Excel.Application{};    
}
```

it works too. it is not magic!

I hope it helps